# Rails + RSpec - spec/support files not being required; giving "Uninitialized Constant (NameError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

In my current project, I am not able to run any of the test case because I am getting the following error:

```
/home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/spec/support/helpers.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Features (NameError)
```

Full trace:

```
/home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::ZIP
/home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of ZIP was here
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/coverage. 11 / 56 LOC (19.64%) covered.
/home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/spec/support/helpers.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Features (NameError)
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core.rb:112:in `configure'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/spec/support/helpers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/spec/spec_helper.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/spec/spec_helper.rb:16:in `each'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/spec/spec_helper.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:932:in `load'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:932:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:932:in `each'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:932:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:100:in `run'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:31:in `invoke'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/harsh/Documents/viburnix/cloud/viburnix/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

`spec/spec_helper.rb` is the standard file generated by `spec:install` and includes:

`Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }`

In `spec/support/helpers.rb`, I have:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Features::SessionHelpers, type: :feature
  config.include Mongoid::Matchers, type: :model
  config.include AuthenticationHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

And it gives error on line 2: `Features::SessionHelpers`.

Seems like it is either not requiring the code at all or just not loading in correct order.

The problem is that in a team of 7, I am the only one who is not able to run `spec`. Any help or direction is much needed and would be appreciated.

Comment: I just cloned the same project in another folder, ran bundle install, but still getting the same error.

Comment: I just compared the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock with 2 other members of my team. The Gemfile and lock versions are identical. :(

Comment: Did you create `Features::SessionHelpers` class in `spec/support/features/session_helpers.rb` file?

Comment: This [blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara) might help..
Make sure you have a Features module declared somewhere and SessionHelpers is namespaced under the Features module.

Comment: @HarshGupta Can you verify that you did create the `session_helpers` file with proper namespacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply. This project was started by another team and yes all the files, modules and classes were present at right place. The problem was the sequence of loading/requiring (in `spec_helper.rb`) these files. While other people were working happily without any issue, I had to load/require some of the required files earlier.

What baffles me are 2 questions:

1. I am not puzzled it didn't work for me. The requiring of those specific files manually make sense and should have been that way from the start. I am puzzled at how did it work for other people?
2. I tried making a virtual machine exactly the same way as other people. Yet I faced the issue, debunking the myth that this has to do with OS or shell etc.

I have added those lines to `spec_helper.rb` and I comment them after running tests but before committing my work.

Comment: Let me post the link to your entire discussion @Harsh Gupta: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1165. It really helped me out in this one.